# Using Mule how to pull a file from an FTP site in response to an incoming VM event?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When I get a triggering event on an inbound VM queue I want to pull a file from an FTP site.
The problem is the flow needs to be triggered by the incoming VM message not the FTP file's availability.

I cannot figure out how to have what is essentially two inputs. I considered using a content enricher but it seems to call an outbound endpoint. The Composite Source can have more than one input, but it runs when any of the message sources trigger it, not a sum of sources.
I am setting up an early alert resource monitoring of FTP, file systems, databases, clock skew, trading partner availability, etc. Periodically I would like to read a custom configuration file that tells what to check and where to do it and send a specific request to other flows.
Some connectors like File and FTP do not lend themselves to be triggered by an outside event. The database will allow me to select on the fly but there is no analog for File and FTP.
It could be that I am just thinking about it in the wrong light but I am a little stumped. I tried having the VM event trigger a script that starts a flow that had an initial state of “stopped” and that flow pulls from an FTP site but VM seems to not play well with starting and stopping flows, and it begins to feel like a 'cluttered' solution.

Thank you,
- Don

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of scenarios, you should use the [Mule requester module](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/).

[image: example of requester in studio]

Comment: Thanks Victor, this does look like what I need.  
I loaded the module into Anypoint Studio and then got pulled into a different project for a couple of days. I will circle back to this.  
I really appreciate your answer. I was running out of options, creative or otherwise.

Comment: Right you are Victor. It works great for both my file and FTP needs. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: To say the truth the transport themselves should provide this feature, and they will but in the meantime this does the trick as clean as possible.